# The camera goes beyond the track i have it following

Tags: animation, camera

I am new to blender and just messing around with the camera and I have noticed that when i play the animation it follows the path and then when it gets to the end it just keeps going in a straight line and I don't know what to do.

[image]

Comment: You can bake the motion of the camera to keyframes, and then you will have greater control over stopping it

Comment: What would you like it to do instead?

Comment: I wanted it to stop at the end of the track Samuel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

select your path and under "path animation" select "clamp":

[image]

Comment: Thanks Chris that was really helpful.

Comment: You are welcome